# getting index from array returns 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I'm relatively new to Javascript but I'm making a memory game in html using javascript.
I'm using an api to fetch 18 images and I put them all in an array twice, so I can shuffle the list and assign the images to my 36 cards.

```
var images_list = [];
var response = fetch('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    images_list.push(data.message);
    images_list.push(data.message);
  });
shuffle(images_list);
```

After this I get all the 36 memory-cards and assign them all one of the pictures.

```
var backViewList = document.getElementsByClassName("back-view");

        for (var i=0; i < backViewList.length; i++) {

            console.log(images_list);


            var img = backViewList[i].querySelector("img");
            img.src = images_list[i]; 
        }
```

the `console.log(images_list);` shows me an array with 36 url's to images, as you would expect. But when I `console.log(images_list[0];` or any other index, this returns undefined. I can't seem to figure out why he does this. Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: `fetch()` is an **asynchronous** mechanism.

Comment: Please see [How do I return the response from an aynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/438992), which this duplicates.

Comment: but the ```console.log(images_list)``` shows me a perfect array with the data in it.

Comment: @PiiMY The first snippet accesses `images_list` before the `fetch` has completed.

Comment: @PiiMY `console.log` sometimes performs lazy lookups of object references. `console.log(images_list.length)` will show `0`; `console.log(images_list.slice())` will show the current copy of the array. See [Is Chrome’s JavaScript console lazy about evaluating objects?](/q/4057440/4642212).

Comment: but how do i fix this? Because when I use await the rest of my game completely crashes.

Comment: @PiiMY How are you trying to use `await`? See [top-level `await`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#top_level_await).

Comment: @PiiMY: "How do i fix this" could potentially involve significant logical changes, we don't really know the overall structure of your code.  The underlying fact however is that you can't use data fetched from the server before that data has been received by the client.  Whatever operation is to be performed on the data fetched from the server would need to be performed *after* it's received.  In the code shown that would be in the `.then()` callback.